# How to reindex into an existing index without erasing previous data

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to adapt data from an old format into a new format like so:

```json
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
    ArrayList convertField(def str) {
      // [complicated conversion]
      return reformatted_data;
    }
  
    ctx._source.specific_field = convertField(ctx._source.specific_field);
    """
  }
}
```

For the sake of a load test I would like to duplicate the data into the new index (it doesnt need to be exaclty the same, some scripted alterations would be fine).

The problem is, everytime I run the reindex, all data in the target index is deleted and replaced bu the new batch. How do I keep the current data and add to it, instead of replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the `_id` field of the reindexed documents to `null`, using the script field. This will generate a new GUID for the reindexed document. In your case:

POST /_reindex

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
    ArrayList convertField(def str) {
      // [complicated conversion]
      return reformatted_data;
    }
  
    ctx._source.specific_field = convertField(ctx._source.specific_field);
    ctx._id = null
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's better than manually editting the ID.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that can only be one document with a given `_id`.

For my test all I did was to edit each `_id`.

```
ctx._id = ctx._id + "_1";
```